# Logitech Presenter R800 and micro / mini USB

Tags: usb, logitech-presenter

I was wondering (because I'm thinking about buying a tablet) if a USB dongle for the Logitech Presenter R800 works also via a micro or mini USB port? Are these ports sufficient to power to device? I couldn't find any answer using Google.

Answer (score 0):

Just saw your question and it made me curious. So I tried my colleague's R800 on my Nexus 7 tablet, using my OTG USB cable as adapter (google it if you haven't heard of it, but it's cheap and lets you use USB mouse and keybord, USB flash drives, things like that). My tablet is rooted, but I do not think you actually need to do that for this to work. Caveat emptor though.

The forward/back keys work on some programs, like Mantano Reader, Chrome, Facebook, but not on others, like Play Books, at least as far as I could tell. The presenter is basically a wireless keyboard with very few keys, so whatever hardware that would recognizer such a keyboard will work with it, I suspect. Works fine on Linux, for example.

So, I suppose whatever programs that recognize "page up" and "page down" commands should work here. Good luck!